# Create Dictionary from Table using first list as header

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using the following table, I want to create a dictionary with fruits as the keys and the quantity as values

```
grades = [['Fruit', 'Apples', 'Bananas', 'Coconut'],
        ['Jim', '4', '5', '6'],
        ['Kevin', '7', '8', '10'],
        ['Clayton', '8', '9', '2']]
```

For Example :

```
QuantityList['Apples'] == [4,7,8]
```

I have the following code below but i get a "'list' object is not callable" error.

```
num=[y[1:] for y in table[1:]]
fruits = table[0][1:]
QuantityList={y[0]: {int(i) for i in num()} for y in fruits}
print(QuantityList)
```

Can someone provide some direction on how to fix this?

Comment: Your example is inconsistent. What is `grades`?

Comment: @DYZ true, table should have been called "grades"

Comment: yup yup.my mistake. I'm actually using a larger dataset, and created a sample problem out of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like what you want is:

```
QuantityList = {y: [int(x[i]) for x in num] for i, y in enumerate(fruits)}
print(QuantityList) # {'Coconut': [6, 10, 2], 'Apples': [4, 7, 8], 'Bananas': [5, 8, 9]}
```

Answer (score 0):

For 1-line sport:
The map and zip functions are useful in situations like this:

```
grades = [['Fruit', 'Apples', 'Bananas', 'Coconut'],
         ['Jim', '4', '5', '6'],
         ['Kevin', '7', '8', '10'],
         ['Clayton', '8', '9', '2']]

result = {row[0] : row[1:] for row in list(map(list, zip(*grades)))[1:]}
print(result)
```

gives you

```
{'Apples': ['4', '7', '8'], 'Bananas': ['5', '8', '9'], 'Coconut': ['6', '10', '2']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having that error because you wrote `num()` instead of `num` in the `QuantityList` variable assignment line. You defined `num` as a list but you are trying to call it as a function with the parentheses.

Another solution could be to use `zip` to group the columns and then build the dict (after skip the first column `('Fruit', 'Jim', 'Kevin', 'Clayton')`):

```
columns = zip(*grades)
next(columns) # To skip ('Fruit', 'Jim', 'Kevin', 'Clayton')
QuantityList = {c[0]: [int(n) for n in c[1:]] for c in columns}
print(QuantityList) # {'Bananas': [5, 8, 9], 'Apples': [4, 7, 8], 'Coconut': [6, 10, 2]}
```

With `zip(*grades)` we are passing every row in `grades` as parameters to `zip` function and `zip` groups the values by column.